# Rails relationship between Company and workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am still new to Rails and learning to build a simple app.
The idea is there is a user who can create a post "listing" and the user can join that listing. user can join or the listing's owner can add users and its need approve from the other side.

erd:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ux0e78g8l3c38p6/erd.pdf?dl=0

How can I check if the user already joined listing from listing view and user view? 
if a user request to join listing then the listing in set to pending, but how can I only allow the owner of listing to approve it?
And if a listing's owner request to add user, how I only allow that user to approve the request? 
Should I create new column for ex: requested_by to check who created the relationship and check for that? or any other way?
Thanks

User model: user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

has_many :employeeships

has_many :pending_listings,   -> {where employeeships: { status: 0 }}, :through => :employeeships, source: :listing
has_many :accepted_listings,  -> {where employeeships: { status: 1 }}, :through => :employeeships, source: :listing

# User owner listing relation
has_many :listings, ->{ order "created_at Desc" }

end
```

Listing model: listing.rb

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :employeeships

  has_many :pending_users,   -> {where employeeships: { status: 0 }}, :through => :employeeships, source: :user
  has_many :accepted_users,  -> {where employeeships: { status: 1 }}, :through => :employeeships, source: :user


  # User owner listing relation
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Employeeship model: employeeship.rb

```
class Employeeship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :listing

  # User status for listings
  enum status: [ :pending, :accepted ]

end
```

Employeeships controller: employeeships_controller.rb

```
class EmployeeshipsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @user_listing = Employeeship.create(user: user, listing: listing, status: 0)
    flash[:info] = "#{@user_listing.user.name} was successfully added to #{@user_listing.listing.title}"
    redirect_to listing
  end



  def update
    user = params[:user_id]
    listing = params[:listing_id]
    @employeeship = Employeeship.where(user: user, listing: listing).first
    @employeeship.status = 1
    if @employeeship.update(employeeship_params)
      flash[:success] = "Employeeship was successfully accepted."
      redirect_to request.referrer
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = params[:user_id]
    listing = params[:listing_id]
    @employeeship = Employeeship.where(user: user, listing: listing).first
    @employeeship.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Employeeship was successfully deleted."
    #redirect_to listing_path()
    redirect_to request.referrer
  end


  private
    def employeeship_params
      params.permit(:user, :listing, :status)
    end

end
```

Routes.eb

```
resources :users

resources :listings

resources :employeeships, only: [:create, :destroy, :update]
```

Listings/show.html.rb

```
<%= link_to 'Join Listing', employeeships_path(user_id: current_user, listing_id: @listing.id), method: :post %>

<% @listing.pending_users.each do |user| %>
    <%= link_to user.name, user_path(user) %>
    <%= link_to 'Accept', employeeship_path(user_id: user, listing_id: @listing.id), method: :put, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
    <%= link_to 'Cancel', employeeship_path(user_id: user, listing_id: @listing.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: do you need the info, then you have to save the data.  Maybe you can use the state-machine https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine requested_id is not so good. Rails used _id columns as columns for foreign-keys.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely add `requested_by` column. Then you can do something like `if listing.requested_by == listing.owner` to figure out whether the person requesting is the owner or another user.

Comment: Just a comment. I think you need to use `user_id: current_user.id` or `user_id: user.id` in show. Is it working ok without the `.id`?

Comment: Thanks @TarynEast for your answer, Not sure why amarradi dose not agree with this idea..
Hi Pablo, Its working fine without add .id :) I think Rails smart to know that or anyone could explain better for us.